# Como obtener los 3 ultimos valores de un string[][ en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

tengo un array de string que me va guardando valores de 3 en 3 , tiene esta forma

```
 string[] = (2,00 , 1,5 , 0,50 , 1,5 , 1,5 , 0,00);
```

Queria saber como sacar los 3 ultimos valores del array unicamente, no se con que función se podria hacer.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hay muchas opciones para conseguir eso. Has probado alguna?

Comment: `string[string[].length] , string[(string[].length-1)] , string[(string[].length-2)]` mas o menos asi

Comment: gracias por responder, me he comido un poco el coco y lo he sacado asi:       Console.WriteLine("1 " + valores[valores.Count() - 1]);
            string cambio = valores[valores.Count() - 1];
            Console.WriteLine("2 " + valores[valores.Count() - 2]);
            string introducido = valores[valores.Count() - 2];
            Console.WriteLine("3 " + valores[valores.Count() - 3]);
            string apagar = valores[valores.Count() - 3];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay muchisímas maneras de conseguirlo. Podrías usar un bucle `for` por ejemplo:

```
for (int i=array.Length-1;i> array.Length - 4; i--)
{
    var elemento= array[i];
}
```

Pero usando Linq es algo muy sencillo y en una sola línea de código:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "2,00", "1,5", "0,50", "1,3", "1,5", "0,00" };
var tresUltimos = array.Reverse().Take(3).ToArray();
```

- [`Reverse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netframework-4.7.2) -> Damos la vuelta al array
- [`Take`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) -> Obtiene el numero de elementos que le indicamos
- `ToArray` -> Devolvemos el resultado como un `Array`